# When directly opening a download in Microsoft Edge, browser download files to some random location

Tags: download, microsoft-edge, windows-11-v22h2

I have configured my Edge to download every file to `C:\Trashed`:

[image]

and to *Ask me what to do with each download*. And this works just like charm, when I click *Save as* in the download dialog:

[image]

But when I click *Open*, it download files to some temporary / random location (i.e. `MicrosoftEdgeDownloads` folder, for example -- `C:\Users\[username]\AppData\Local\Temp\MicrosoftEdgeDownloads\3c0b01e5-9a28-4e70-8214-8d796783305e`) instead of `C:\Trashed`.

Is this *a bug* or *by design*?

I am asking, because when file is downloaded into above temporary location, my system (Windows 11) always prevents running applications from that location (actually: prevents applications run form there from creating temporary directories).

Therefore each click to *Open* in Microsoft Edge ends with something like that:

[image]

And in order to actually run such application I must always manually copy-paste it to some other location (i.e. from temporary directory to `C:\Trashed` etc.).

I am trying to figure out how to prevent this behavior.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's by [design](https://www.tenforums.com/browsers-email/139285-where-does-microsoft-edge-save-file-when-you-click-run.html), *intentionally preventing malware from running in that location,* while allowing the anti-malware app to  to check the download before the file(s) are moved to the specified folder. You'll notice the same with some other applications, such as 7-Zip, for the same reason.

However, *after the download is complete and vetted*, all files should be in your preferred folder. If the download has *not* been moved to a location from which it *can* be run, check the particular anti-malware suite on that PC, which could be interfering with that process, and  check or reinstall Edge. It's possible some third-party suite needs to be updated to fix that issue.